# How to indicate count of values in categorical column in Pandas, Python?

Tags: pandas, pivot, aggregation

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
ID CAT
1  A
1  B
1  A
2  A
2  B
2  A
1  B
1  A
```

I'd like to have a table that indicates the number of occurance per CAT values for each ID in different columns like this:

```
ID CAT_A_NUM CAT_B_NUM
1  3         2
2  2         1
```

I tried in many ways, like this one with pivot table, but unsuccessfully:

```
df.pivot_table(values='CAT', index='ID', columns='CAT', aggfunc='count')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [**crosstab()**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1],'CAT':['A','B','A','A','B','A','B','A']})
final = pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['CAT'])
final.columns=['CAT_A_NUM','CAT_B_NUM']
final

ID  CAT_A_NUM   CAT_B_NUM
1   3           2
2   2           1
```

Comment: How is decided what is the order of the count columns of the resulted DF? Why CAT_A_NUM is the first, and not CAT_B_NUM?

Comment: Frankly i thought it was sorted alphabetically. Just to be sure, I ran a few tests and yes the results are returned alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use `groupby` + `unstack`

```
df.groupby(["ID","CAT"]).size().unstack()
```

which gives

```
CAT  A  B
ID       
1    3  2
2    2  1
```